# Changing Hover Colors with Inline CSS in CPanel

Tags: css, colors, hover, cpanel, inline

Currently trying to modify a client's website using Cpanel but finding it difficult changing the hover color. How do I change the hover color using inline CSS because modification via the main CSS file seems not to be working? I've tried using the internal styling method but that isn't working either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use :hover or pseudo-classes inline styling but a solution to this could be something like this:

```
<p onMouseOver="this.style.color='#fff'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#000'">Text</p>
```